# How can I check asp membership database roles for a user in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-membership

I have a pure JavaScript/html page (e.g., index.html) that is secured by a Login.aspx page with a asp.net login control. After a user input his account info, I want to get the list of roles that this authenticated user belongs to by using JavaScript in the index.html page. Can someone tell me how to do it?

Many thanks,

Wei

Comment: use AJAX `.load` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ajax call, which is quite easy if you are using jQuery's ajax.

```
$.get('/some/url/to/retrieve/the/roles/from', function(roles) {

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but we don't use jQuery. And I want to get only the roles current user belongs to, I don't know if your code does this. I also don't know what should I use to replace your "/some/url/to/retrieve/the/roles/from". Hope you can give me a more detailed example. Appreciate.